# can "happy" bells toll?

Tags: idioms

can "happy" bells toll: Say wedding bells? or does "toll" have an ominous connotation, suggesting doom, funerals, death, etc.? : "For Whom the Bells Toll", etc.

Answer (score 3):

The authority on this is Edgar Allen Poe, who associates “tolling” with the “iron bells” of the funeral:

> Hear the **tolling** of the bells,
>             Iron bells!
>   What a world of solemn thought their monody compels!
>       In the silence of the night
>       How we shiver with affright
>     At the melancholy menace of their tone!
>       For every sound that floats
>       From the rust within their throats
>             Is a groan.
>       And the people—ah, the people,
>       They that dwell up in the steeple,
>             All alone,
>     And who **tolling**, **tolling**, **tolling**,
>       In that muffled monotone,
>     Feel a glory in so rolling
>       On the human heart a stone—
>   They are neither man nor woman,
>   They are neither brute nor human,
>         They are Ghouls:
>     And their king it is who **tolls**;
>     And he rolls, rolls, rolls,
>           Rolls
>       A pæan from the bells;
>     And his merry bosom swells
>       With the pæan of the bells,
>     And he dances, and he yells:
>     Keeping time, time, time,
>     In a sort of Runic rhyme,
>       To the pæan of the bells,
>           Of the bells:
>     Keeping time, time, time,
>     In a sort of Runic rhyme,
>     To the throbbing of the bells,
>     Of the bells, bells, bells—
>       To the sobbing of the bells;
>     Keeping time, time, time,
>       As he knells, knells, knells,
>     In a happy Runic rhyme,
>     To the rolling of the bells,
>       Of the bells, bells, bells:
>       To the **tolling** of the bells,
>     Of the bells, bells, bells, bells,
>           Bells, bells, bells—
>   To the moaning and the groaning of the bells.

So perhaps you would do better to pick another word for your wedding bells:

> Hear the mellow wedding bells,
>             Golden bells!
>   What a world of happiness their harmony foretells!
>       Through the balmy air of night
>       How they **ring** out their delight!
>         From the molten-golden notes,
>             And all in tune,
>         What a liquid ditty floats
>     To the turtle-dove that listens, while she gloats
>             On the moon!
>         Oh, from out the sounding cells,
>   What a gush of euphony voluminously wells!
>             How it swells!
>             How it dwells
>         On the Future! how it tells
>         Of the rapture that impels
>       To the **swinging** and the **ringing**
>         Of the bells, bells, bells,
>       Of the bells, bells, bells, bells,
>             Bells, bells, bells—
>     To the **rhyming** and the **chiming** of the bells!

You may find ring tones Poe recommends for other occasions [here](http://www.bartleby.com/102/88.html).

Answer (score 1):

Below is the definition from Merriam-Webster.  It seems to me that "toll" is the act of ringing and that it has a neutral connotation. The tolling could be happy or sad depending upon the occasion.

Definition of TOLL

transitive verb
1
:  to sound (a bell) by pulling the rope
2
a :  to give signal or announcement of 
b :  to announce by tolling 
c :  to call to or from a place or occasion 
intransitive verb
:  to sound with slow measured strokes 
Origin of TOLL

Middle English, to pull, drag, toll (a bell), perhaps alteration of toilen to struggle — more at toil
First Known Use: 15th century